# Pointer to vector of structs error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, vector

I'm making a .lib file for a mobile robot.
Currently I'm writing a function for scanning Bluetooth devices.

The function is:

```
struct Device
{
     string DeviceName;
     BTH_ADDR DeviceAddress;
};

void ScanForDevices(vector<Device> *Robot)
    {
        m_bt = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio);

        BluetoothGetRadioInfo(m_radio, &m_bt_info);
        m_search_params.hRadio = m_radio;

        ZeroMemory(&m_device_info, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));
        m_device_info.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);

        m_bt_dev = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&m_search_params, &m_device_info);


        int m_device_id = 0;
        char charDeviceName[250];

        do {
                charDeviceName[250]=NULL;
                Robot->push_back(Device()); 
                //WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,0,m_device_info.szName,-1, charDeviceName,0,NULL, NULL);
                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,0,m_device_info.szName,-1, charDeviceName,250,NULL, NULL);
                Robot[m_device_id]->DeviceName=(string)charDeviceName;
                Robot[m_device_id]->DeviceAddress=m_device_info.Address.ullLong;
                m_device_id++;

            } while(BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev,&m_device_info));

            BluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev);

            BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt);
    }
```

I keep getting:

```
Error   6   error C2819: type 'std::vector<_Ty>' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
Error   7   error C2039: 'DeviceName' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'
Error   8   error C2819: type 'std::vector<_Ty>' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
Error   9   error C2039: 'DeviceAddress' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'
Error   10  IntelliSense: expression must have pointer type 
Error   11  IntelliSense: expression must have pointer type
```

I'm starting C++ and am not really skilled in the use of pointers.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robot is a pointer points to `vector<Device>`. You are confusing yourself with point to vector and vector element accessing. To fix the issue, you could change:

```
Robot[m_device_id]->DeviceName=(string)charDeviceName;
```

to

```
Robot->at(m_device_id).DeviceName = std::string(charDeviceName);
```

Or

```
(*Robot)[m_device_id].DeviceName = std::string(charDeviceName);
```

**Suggestion**:

Better solution is to pass vector by reference instead of pointer.

```
void ScanForDevices(vector<Device> &Robot)
{
    std::string  charDeviceName;   //<<-- use std::string instead of char array
    Robot[m_device_id].DeviceName = charDeviceName;  //<<-- this is better coding style
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.

I will do as suggested.

charDeviceName has to be char although I need string because of WideCharToMultiByte. Is there any better way to convert WCHAR to string?

Comment: use wcstombs? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs, you may still need the array though.

Answer (score 1):

To access `vector<Device> *Robot` element by index, use the following syntax:

```
(*Robot)[m_device_id]
```

Your code should be:

```
(*Robot)[m_device_id].DeviceName=(string)charDeviceName;
```

Note that `->` is replaced by `.` because the vector element has `Device` type, this is not pointer.

Your existing code matches the following vector declaration:

```
vector<Device*> Robot
```

See the difference.

Comment: This is direct answer to your question. However, it is a good idea to change the function prototype, as suggested in billz` answer.